# Yii2 ORDER BY for relational data in ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

I have a query in my controller:

```
$model = Object::find()->where(['id' => $id])->with(['backups'])->one();
```

getBackups is a hasMany() relation, so $model returns several 'backups'.

Is there a way to order the 'backups'?

I have tried the following without results (or errors):

```
 $model = Object::find()
          ->where(['id' => $id])
          ->with(['backups' => function($query) { 
              $query->orderBy(['updated_at' => SORT_DESC]); 
          }])
          ->one();
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine (second one with query ordering callback). Test it with changing order direction (SORT_DESC, SORT_ASC): echo $model->backups[0]->id. Id should change. otherwise I would think that there is only one backup in db.

Comment: I'll have another look at it. Thanks

Comment: I have 3 relational fields showing on the entry i'm watching now. I have tried both sorting options, and i'm echoing the id of backups[0] as you say. I cant get any changing results :/

Comment: Just realized that i'm only returning one field, and the orderBy is sorting that one field, not all the related fields. @user1852788's solution works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can in `Object` model declare sorted relation `backups` with `orderBy`:

```
public function getSortedBackups()
  {

    return $this->hasMany(Backup::className(), ['object_id' => 'id'])->orderBy(['backups.updated_at'=>SORT_DESC]);
  }
```

end when you output these backups:

```
foreach($model->sortedBackups as $backup){
...
}
```